# Selenium python checking if the input type is dropdown

Tags: python, selenium

How to verify if the input type is a dropdown, usually I find it with the type. But in the below HTML code there is no type

[image]

can i do it by verifying if the td contains option tag?

Comment: Could you post a link to the website so we can inspect the full HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Use a name selector instead to find it:

```
elem = webdriver.find_element_by_name("currencyid")
```

If you just know it is a dropdown ahead of time, use the tag selector

```
elem = webdriver.find_element_by_tag_name('select')
```

There is no type (i.e input type="checkbox") because its not an input field.

Comment: i can but it will not work with my case. the purpose of the function is to get the variable from the user and find it type. i.e textbox, checkbox or dropdown and perform actions based on that

Comment: In HTML a dropdown is a select, and text and checkbox are input types.